# Want to change Default caret icon in Bootstrap3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, caret

I want to change default icon that appears when I use

```
<b class="caret"></b>
```

I want to replace it with some FontAwesome icons.
How to do it?

Comment: please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" as it means something else.

Answer (score 5):

just change the class to fontawesome class.
Make sure you have the fontawesome stylesheet

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-caret-down">Caret</i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<b class="fa <your preferred fa icon>"></b>`

include `<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` for the icons.